# Why og:image is always refer to post first image?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I am using Yoast SEO plugin for and Enable Facebook setting:
[image]

And add seperate image for the following post : http://bangla.codingpractise.com/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AF%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BF-%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%A6%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%A8/internet-download-manager-free-download-for-windows-10-with-crack/
[image]

Here is my og:image : http://bangla.codingpractise.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/idm-logo.jpg

But when I try to share my post on facebook, it shows the first image of my post: http://bangla.codingpractise.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Capture.png

Any idea?

Comment: On the post/page you can upload the desired image that you want to be shown on Facebook. Go to the page/post, check the Yoast Settings for social. Here you can upload an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the social share image for your page/post in Yoast instead of MashShare. You may not need MashShare at all. I'm not familiar with it.

[Here's what the Yoast UI looks like for adding the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3NKG.png)